Are these polynomials $g_n(x)$ for $n\ge 2$ Hurwitz polynomials?
Edit: I read about Hurwitz polynomials and it seems like this is what is needed here:
Define
$$
g_n(x) =
\begin{cases}
1, & \text{if } n = 1, \\
x + g_{n-1}(x), & \text{if } n > 1 \text{ is prime}, \\
\prod_{p \mid n} \left( g_p(x) \right)^{v_p(n)}, & \text{if } n > 1 \text{ is composite}.
\end{cases}
$$
Here are some of these polynomials:
1 1
2 x + 1
3 2*x + 1
4 x^2 + 2*x + 1
5 x^2 + 3*x + 1
6 2*x^2 + 3*x + 1
7 2*x^2 + 4*x + 1
8 x^3 + 3*x^2 + 3*x + 1
9 4*x^2 + 4*x + 1
10 x^3 + 4*x^2 + 4*x + 1
11 x^3 + 4*x^2 + 5*x + 1
12 2*x^3 + 5*x^2 + 4*x + 1
13 2*x^3 + 5*x^2 + 5*x + 1
14 2*x^3 + 6*x^2 + 5*x + 1
15 2*x^3 + 7*x^2 + 5*x + 1
16 x^4 + 4*x^3 + 6*x^2 + 4*x + 1
17 x^4 + 4*x^3 + 6*x^2 + 5*x + 1
18 4*x^3 + 8*x^2 + 5*x + 1
19 4*x^3 + 8*x^2 + 6*x + 1
20 x^4 + 5*x^3 + 8*x^2 + 5*x + 1
21 4*x^3 + 10*x^2 + 6*x + 1
22 x^4 + 5*x^3 + 9*x^2 + 6*x + 1
23 x^4 + 5*x^3 + 9*x^2 + 7*x + 1

It seems that empirically we have $\forall n \ge 2$ the polynomial $g_n(x)$ is a Hurwitz polynomial, wich by definition means it has real coefficients and all of its roots have real value $<0$.
This observation with the Lemma which comes afterwards would explain why for $p$ prime we have $g_p(x)$ is irreducible.
Let $G_n(x) := \sum_{k=1}^n g_k(x)$ and let $L(n):=\sum_{k=1}^n \lambda(k) = \sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{\Omega(n)}$. Then using $g_2(-1)=0$ and $g_p(-1)=-1$ for $p>2$ prime, we observe that $G_n(-1) = L(n)+L(\operatorname{floor}(\frac{n}{2}))$ and thus iterating this last equation, we get:
$$L(n) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k G_{\operatorname{floor}(\frac{n}{2^k})}(-1)$$
so this might help in formulating the PNT or RH as described by Landau in terms of these polynomials $G_n$:
PNT $\iff 0 = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k G_{\operatorname{floor}(\frac{n}{2^k})}(-1)$
Of course this might seem far fetched, but I find it interesting that for $p$ prime we seem to always have that $g_p(x)$ is irreducible:
This could be proved if $\operatorname{Re}(z)<0<\frac{1}{2}$ for all roots $z$ of the polynomial $g_p(x)$. Here is a picture of collected roots of some $g_p(x)$ with $p$ prime $\le 100000$.
If all roots have real value $<1-1/2$ then the following Lemma could be applied to the polynomial $P(x):=g_p(x)$ with $n=1$, since $p=g_p(1) = g_p(n)$ is a prime number and $g_p(n-1) = g_p(1-1) = g_p(0) = 1 \neq 0 $:
Lemma (B. Sury, Polynomials with Integer Values, Lemma 1.9):
Let $ P(X) \in \mathbb{Z}[X] $ be a polynomial, and suppose there exists an integer $ n $ such that:

The zeros of $P$ lie in the half-plane $ \text{Re}(z) < n - \frac{1}{2} $.
$P(n - 1) \neq 0$.
$P(n)$ is a prime number.

Then $P(X)$ is irreducible.

I find it interesting that such simple polynomials can encode some properties of primes.
So my questions are:

Are all polynomials ( $n\ge 2$) Hurwitz polynomials? (The difficult part seems to be if we consider $g_p(x)$ for $p$ prime.)

If 1. is too restrictive, can it be proven that $g_p(x)$ is irreducible if $p$ is a prime?


If it helps, here are some simple observations: $g_n(0) = 1 \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, $g_n(1) = n \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$.
Thanks for your help!
Related questions:
Polynomials for natural numbers and irreducible polynomials for prime numbers?
Are most prime numbers symmetric?
Are there infinitely many $g$- or $m$-primes?

related question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/69411/bound-on-the-real-part-of-roots-of-a-polynomial

Perhaps the Hurwitz stability criterion provides some insight?

@StevenClark: Thanks for the link.
